# How to stretch out animation time for a volume object

Tags: animation, constraints, volumetrics, timeline, interpolation

Blender volumes are great; particularly when I've got a scene (as I do right now) with a number of fluid effects going on. I can simply save them into a directory as a bunch of OpenVDB files and import them as a volume, once I have them looking right. This is great for animations in which I want to add physics effects incrementally.

The problem is, I have my volume (a cloud from a firework) saved in a folder, but need to stretch it out in sync with an expanded animation length. I decided to expand my animation from 250 frames to 700. However, I can't figure out how to get the frames of the volume to step any slower and match this change.

[image: Sample of volume pane]

I see plenty of possibilities for changing the start frame, the frame count, the resolution, and other things; but nothing for interpolation or stretching out time. How does one do this?

Comment: How should be calculated missing information for frames ..., 2, 3, ..., 5, 6, ..., 8, 9, ... for such extended animation? Volumetrics are like 3D texture what would be algorithm to calculate transition between those? For changing start you have Offset parametr.